# How should I get rid of TFS Branches properly?

Tags: tfs, branch

I am wondering how I should properly get rid of branches that no longer have any purpose. Right now even if i delete them and commit they are still listed as branches in the properties windows for a particular branching root (directory). If I select merge I don't get an option to merge to the deleted branch which obviously is as expected but therefore I am puzzled about the branch still showing up in the properties window.

Any explanation on this behavior would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

I had a situation where a branch had been deleted and there was no purpose for it to stick around.  I couldn't get `tf` destroy to work until I found out the deletion number of the directory like Damien mentioned.  I couldn't get that ID with `tf` properties since there was no local copy and no server copy based on the error messages.

I was able to get the full TFS path by using:

```
tf dir $/MyPathTo/TheParent/Directory /deleted
```

Then I found the postfixed ";Ident" to the directory and could issue:

```
tf destroy $/MyPathTo/TheParent/Directory/TheDirectoryToGetRidOff;Ident
```

Damien your answer helped me out - thanks.  I thought I'd include the syntax that got me through it to go along with your post.

Answer (score 14):

The deleted branch is only marked as deleted at a moment in time and it's possible to still get to the code if you sync to a changeset or time before that delete operation.

If you do not want to have the file in the branch in the database at all you can use the `tf destroy` command line:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx)

As your branch is already deleted you'll need to use `tf dir /deleted` to find the deletion number of that branch in order to destroy the files.

Answer (score 1):

Please use following method to destroy branch in your TFS Project
you should have permission to delete branch - you should be a part of project collection admin.
Open Visual Studio Command prompt with admin previlage.
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE>
tf destroy $/MyProject/Main/Bin /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/myproject