# Team Foundation Server 2010: Can I delete a branch, but save its history?

Tags: branch, history

In Team Foundation Server 2010, I have created a source control branch for a major project that I want to be temporary. After the project is closed, I'd like to tie off the temporary branch, merge it into my Main branch, and then delete it. I want to delete it simply so I don't have a temporary branch hanging around for all time. BUT, I don't want to lose the check-in history from this branch.

So, my question is can I delete a branch that has been merged into other branches without deleting that branch's history as well?

Comment: See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323834/how-should-i-get-rid-of-tfs-branches-properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleted branches are basically hidden, not really deleted.  This means they don't show up in Source Control Explorer (unless you have the show deleted files option turned on), but the history for the branch should still be available via the annotate tool and when viewing history on a file in any branch you merged the branch back into.

Comment: Can you physically delete a branch?

Comment: Try search for destroy branch

Comment: I asked because other people reading this question might benefit from the answer to my question as well.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c6ce5181-7492-4c5a-8ea2-3b9de0b7e7eb/using-tf-destroy-to-really-remove-a-branch